# CCDA parsing using Mirth Connect

Tags: mirth

I'm working on a project that sends us some CDA documents so I have to  parse and extract the data using Mirth Connect as interface engine and save them in a Mirth Results (provider portal). Any idea what is the best way to approach this like configuration or coding to a channel in Mirth to load content of CCD document and extract fields from the CCD document and populate the channel variables map.

Comment: Yes, you can map fields in Mirth if your CDA/CCD is stable and you know for sure it will not change. Yes, you can use other mechanisms such as XSLT or MDHT to pre-parse your document. Considering a wide variety of nested relationships even within a single segment level template, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to come across this question. I think you would have got the answer, anyway let me share what I have, it may help you in fututre

The CDA document that you fetch is bascially parsed as a XML document. You can either use the MDHT libraries or a simple javascipt that Mirth tool support.

It is not always mandatory that you have to go for external libraries. I have worked with CCDA document structure which is parsible with Javascript supported by mirth.

It depends of what process you follow.If its only one CDA document you are parsing, then fetch it in inbound template, the CDA document will contain a lot of sections like patient demographics, vital signs and other fields. To provide a generalized solution we have to loop through the segments to get rid of referring index inside the array.

Example for looping thorugh care plan section:

```
function parseCarePlan(section) {
    var careplan = [],
        care, entries = section['entry'],
        entry;
    for (j = 0; j < entries.length(); j++) {
        entry = entries[j];
        care = {};
      care.date = entry['procedure']['effectiveTime']['center']['@value'].toString();
            care.text = entry['procedure']['code']['text'].toString();
            care.code = entry['procedure']['code']['@code'].toString();
}
```

We have to create a JSON data from the XML (CDA) and then provide the JSON objects inside the Database

Comment: I am working on the same. Can you please share the code for  CCDA XML parsing in mirth connect. Thanks

Comment: Hi sarav, I'm checking for the source channel. Once I get I will share with you

Comment: @VibinGuvera Did you get this? If yes, can you please post it here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for the Mirth Results software you will have a support contract to help you answer questions like this. In fact the Mirth Results software has very good native support for CCDA documents. Mirth did very well at Connectathon in 2014 with their CCDA library.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/mdht/ to parse CCDA, Create a jar for parsing your CCD document and call that jar - > public method which will accept document and return JSON as response to mirth connect javascript.

Its working for me.

Comment: The link shared above is going to some blog.